# AutoCompleteTextView suggestion results sticking to screen when they shouldn't

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

my `AutoCompleteTextView` is created with a custom adapter to show suggestions for ~3000 Strings. while typing in the input view, suggestions are coming up as expected, except that sometimes a chunk of the dropdown view with suggestions is being clipped or looks like its detached from the `AutoCompleteTextView`.  this extra chunk of the dropdown apears to be holding previous suggestions that are no longer relevent.  upon clicking a suggestion or typing more letters - the "stuck" dropdown piece disapears.

edit: i find that once the `AutoCompleteTextView` is only showing one suggestion after showing more than one, the problem occurs

Why is this happening? How can i fix it?

Right now i am trying a few things(none of which are working):

-adding a `TextWatcher` on the `AutoCompleteTextView` and invalidating the `AutoCompleteTextView` in the `onTextChanged` method.

-`getWindow().getDecorView().invalidate();` on the `Activity` containing this `AutoCompleteTextView` in the `onTextChanged` method

edit: this is only happening on the samsung galaxy s phone running 2.1 sdk version 7

Comment: samsung galaxy s phone running 2.1 sdk version 7

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. On my Samsung i5801 the auto complete shows above and is cut of? I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953041/android-autocompletetextview-not-rendering-correctly. It works fine on my nexus 1.

Comment: i was not able to find a solution. :(